# XmlAgg SQL function Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Oracle's XLMAGG function. I use XMLAGG instead of LISTAGG because LISTAGG has a size limit of 4000 bytes.

The query I have made does what I want it to do, however, at the beginning I want to remove the extra `br>` that gets added in the beginning.

---

My query:

```
SELECT
SUBSTR(
  xmlcast(
    xmlagg(
      xmlelement(a, '<br>' || SUBSTR(mtn, 7, 4))
      order by mtn
    ) AS CLOB
  ), 2
) mtn_list
FROM share_req where cust_id = 094435571;
```

---

The results:

```
br>3216<br>3342<br>3439<br>3518<br>3767<br>3926<br>0240<br>0498<br>5328<br>9455
```

but I want the results to be like this:

```
3216<br>3342<br>3439<br>3518<br>3767<br>3926<br>0240<br>0498<br>5328<br>9455
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, `listagg` may work better instead of substr-ing out the leading tag.

```
SQL> select listagg(object_id,'<br>')   WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY object_id)  from user_objects;

LISTAGG(OBJECT_ID,'<BR>')WITHINGROUP(ORDERBYOBJECT_ID)                                                                                                                                  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
93000<br>93001<br>93002<br>93415<br>94093<br>94094<br>94242<br>94243<br>94244<br>94363<br>94479<br>94480<br>94502<br>94507<br>94636<br>94753<br>94754<br>94755<br>94756<br>94757<br>9476
1<br>94762<br>94881<br>94891<br>95022<br>95023<br>95032<br>95033<br>95034<br>95035<br>95036<br>95037<br>95164<br>95165<br>95283
```

Or with the 4k limit issue, change the xmlelement call to move the 
 to next argument vs concatenating.

```
SQL> set long 1000000000
SQL> SELECT
  2    xmlcast(
  3      xmlagg(
  4        xmlelement(b, object_id,'<br>')
  5        order by object_id
  6      ) AS CLOB
  7  ) mtn_list
  8  FROM user_objects;
MTN_LIST                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
93000<br>93001<br>93002<br>93415<br>94093<br>94094<br>94242<br>94243<br>94244<br>94363<br>94479<br>94480<br>94502<br>94507<br>94636<br>94753<br>94754<br>94755<br>94756<br>94757<br>94761<br>94762<br>94881<br>94891<br>95022<br>95023<br>95032<br>95033<br>95034<br>95035<br>95036<br>95037<br>95164<br>95165<br>95283<br>95288<br>
```

Comment: Thanks but i should have added that I can't use Listagg because listagg has a limit size of 4000 bytes

Comment: Got it. Added another option now

Comment: Thank you! This works but it ends it with an extra `<br>` at the end but i think i can work around that.

Comment: Hi actually i need the last four digits of the mtn column but not sure how to do that with the SQL you provided?